# Display image URL in Picture Library View

Tags: picture-library, image

I have a requirement where there will be a single Picture Library for the entire application and all application images will be there, I want a URL column in the Picture Library View where user can copy the URL and use it for certain functionalities.

Comment: Will you be able to use workflows (SharePoint Designer, Nintex)?

Comment: no i cannot use workflows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use JSLink to populate the image Url. Create a column called "ImageUrl" and use below script to populate the field value.

```
(function () {

var imageUrlFiledTemplateContext = {};
imageUrlFiledTemplateContext.Templates = {};
imageUrlFiledTemplateContext.Templates.Fields = {

    'ImageUrl': { 'View': ImageUrlFiledTemplate }
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(imageUrlFiledTemplateContext);
```

})();

```
function ImageUrlFiledTemplate(ctx) {
    var imageUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + ctx.listUrlDir + "/" + ctx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef;
    return imageUrl;
}
```